# Delete an user in Android using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, delete-row

I am trying to develop an activity to delete an user from mysql table. Once I have logged into the application, I want the users to click a button if they want to delete their account. When I click the button I get these errors:

```
22416-22416/etsiit.etsiitcast_def E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: etsiit.etsiitcast_def, PID: 22416
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
        at etsiit.etsiitcast_def.PerfilFragment$1.onClick(PerfilFragment.java:67)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is my delete user.php function:

```
<?php
require_once 'connectbd.php';
// connecting to database
$this->db = new DB_Connect();
$this->db->connect();

$query = "DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";

mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
  echo("El usuario ha sido eliminado.");
} else {
  echo("Error al eliminar el usuario.");
}
?>
```

And here is my Android activity code:

```
Button delete = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "http://"+IP_Server+"/etsiitcast_db/deleteuser.php";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            try {
                client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            } catch(IOException e) {
                //do something here
            }
        }
    });
```

Where IP_SERVER is my server address. 
Tell me if some more code is needed.

Comment: If you open in web this php code, is it working? Edit: using delete limit 1 without order is not a good way. The results may not be unique!

Comment: Always read your logcat. `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` This is your problem.

Comment: Also, you might want to check that HttpClient is deprecated, and you should use other connections, such as the new default HttpURLConnection (But I preffer and suggest Volley)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android you can not make network activities on main thread what you need to is move network activity to background thread using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or better way use a asynchronous networking library like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [Android-Async-Http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). I ued async-http before and i think it was good.Below i put some kind of example might help you out

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();Button delete = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        client.get("http://"+IP_Server+"/etsiitcast_db/deleteuser.php", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // feedback to user
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        // called when request is retried
    }
```

});
});

Comment: Np man glad it helped also check out Volley it is from gooogle and people use it frequently

Answer (score 3):

In Android, you should not make network calls on the main Thread. Otherwise, the UI would freeze. To avoid this, Android now throws NetworkOnMainThreadException.

So, you should make all your network calls in background. To do this, you may use :

- AsyncTasks
- Loaders
- basic Threads...

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed your http call in an AsyncTask in order to not be processed by the main thread.